Size of epsilon net with uniformly distributed points
Consider $N$ vectors $X_1,\cdots,X_N\in \mathbb R^n$ uniformly distributed in a cube $[0,1]^n$.
What condition on $N$ such that $\{X_1,\cdots,X_N\}$ forms an $\epsilon$-net for this cube, with high probability?

No condition on $N$ can possibly ensure that "${X_1,\cdots,X_N}$ forms an $\epsilon$-net for this cube" with probability $1$.

@IosifPinelis I should mention that it holds "with high probability" is enough for my case. I re-edited the question.

Is $\epsilon$ fixed? Is $n$ fixed?

@IosifPinelis $\epsilon,n$ are not fixed.

Anyhow, now you have an answer without assuming $\epsilon$ and/or $n$ to be fixed.

$\newcommand\ep\epsilon$Suppose that $k:=1/\ep$ is an integer. Partition the cube $C:=[0,1]^n$ in the standard manner into cubes $C_1,\dots,C_{k^n}$ each of edgelength $1/k=\ep$. Let
$$N_j:=\sum_{i=1}^N 1(X_i\in C_j).$$
Then
$$P(\{X_1,\dots,X_N\}\text{ is not an $\ep$-net}) \\ 
\le P(\exists j\in\{1,\dots,k^n\}\ N_j=0) \\
\le k^n P(N_1=0)=k^n P(X_1\notin C_1)^N \\ 
=k^n (1-1/k^n)^N
<k^n\exp(-N/k^n).$$
So, for the random set $\{X_1,\dots,X_N\}$ to be an $\ep$-net (in the $\ell_\infty$-metric, which makes sense for the cube $C=[0,1]^n$) with high probability, it is enough that
$$M:=N/k^n-\ln(k^n)=N\ep^n+n\ln\ep\to\infty.$$

Probably makes sense to rewrite it in terms of $\epsilon$ at the end.

Hmm why is that an upper bound on the probability that it is a net? The diameter of each cube is $\sqrt{n}\epsilon$, not just $\epsilon$.

@ChristopherKing : Done. Thank you for your comment.

@MarcusM : I have now added "(in the $\ell_\infty$-metric, which makes sense for the cube $C=[0,1]^n$)".

Why the downvote? Is anything wrong with this answer?
